# No Tests Found Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

Right clicking on a package and selecting `Run Tests...` results in the message `No tests were found`. In earlier versions of Android Studio my tests were found and would run using this method. Running test classes individually seems to work still. I've tried `Invalidate Cache / Restart`, but still running into the same issue.

Logs:

```
---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
exclude patterns:0 test classes found in package '<default package>'

Process finished with exit code 254
Empty test suite.
```

Any point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Onik Current Android Studio 3.3 (canary 12) does not fix this issue. Create new project and unit tests dont run (no tests found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in Android Studio version 3.2.1

Comment: It now detects the tests, but changes to the tests are not detected for some reason so you're very often running old tests. Have you found a workaround besides running the tests from console?

Comment: Hey @Pin! I just tried and my changes were picked up right away. I would suggest creating another post for your issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 6):

I've seen this happen when AS tries to run *unit* tests (`test/` folder) instead of *instrumentation* tests (`androidTest/` folder) or the package specification for the configuration is wrong.

1. Make sure that when you right click a folder to run the package of tests, and select "Run", that the icon has a little droid on it to indicate it's treating the folder as android tests:

   [image]

   If it doesn't, continue to step 2. If it does, skip to step 3.
2. Sometimes AS gets confused and thinks Android tests are unit tests. To fix that, click the Run Configuration icon in the toolbar and select "Edit Configurations..."

   [image]

   You should see an option for Android Tests:

   [image]

   Select this and copy that configuration, then on the right, change it from "All in Module" to "All in Package"
3. Make sure the configuration for the package tests specifies the *full* package you want to test:

   [image]

Once your configuration is correctly set up to run *Android* tests and explicitly indicate the full and correct package of tests to run, it should work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: your image is some different from Android Studio 3.2. I guess 'Test Kind:' set to 'All in package', 'Search for tests:' set to 'In single module', and ' Use classpath of module:' set to module for test. And I sadly still failed tests.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate caches and restart fixed this for me, always worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JUnit 5 and already have JUnit 4 synced in your build.gradle then make sure that @Test annotation should be annotated from import `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Answer (score 1):

This is classic. Some of these steps might help:

1. Kill Gradle daemons: `./gradlew --stop`
2. Reimport the project: close the Android Studio window, delete the project from the list of recent projects, Import again.
3. Report it to the Tools team: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs

Comment: I'd say this is classic in the sense that one updates AS as soon as a new release is available and then regrets doing it...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I inadvertently had both JUnit4 and JUnit5 on the classpath.

Even though I was trying to use JUnit5 in my tests, one of my test dependencies had a transitive dependency on the older version.

After cleaning up the classpath Android Studio (3.2.1) was able to find the tests again.